# How to pass an list of objects to view and populate them in input fields dynamically

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

Im passing a list objects to the view using Spring model attribute. And in the view im trying to populate set of inputs dynamically using jquery as below :

passing the list from the controller :

```
  List<String> supplierNames = Arrays.asList("address1", "address2", "address3");
  model.addAttribute("consumerAddresses", supplierNames);
```

view (jsp):

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
   <div><input type="text" id='label1'><input type="text" id='address1'></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var consumerAddresses = "${consumerAddresses}";
    var max_fields      = 10; 
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 

    for (i = 0; i < consumerAddresses.length; i++) {
         $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" id="label' + i + '" value=' + consumerAddresses[i] + '/><input type="text" 
         id="address' + i + '" value=' + consumerAddresses[i] + '/></div>');
    }

  });
</script>
```

Now the issue is consumerAddresses are passed as array `[address1, address2, address3]` but in input fields its populated as `[/` `a/` `d/` likewise. what has gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `consumerAddresses` you have not an array, it's a string.
And then when you're trying to iterate over it you just take some chars from it.
You need to convert string to an array before iterating through it.
In this case you can use `split` method.

```
var consumerAddressesArray = consumerAddresses.replace(/[[\]']+/g,'').split(", ");
```

After this operations you will have

```
[
"address1",
"address2",
"address3"
]
```

inside your `consumerAddressesArray` variable.

And make sure that you have trimmed all rudimentary chars. I mean `[`,  (space), `]`. In my example I've used regex for that (`.replace(/[[\]']+/g,'')`). It will replace square brackets with empty string.

Comment: thanks for the answer. is there a way to do this without splitting this? i mean, cant i access the original list from the javascript which is passing from model attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can get value which is return by spring mvc in some jsp variable then use for-loop in jsp to iterate through that list i.e :

```
<%
 //get value in jsp variable
 //i.e :request.getAttribute("consumerAddresses");
 //here  i assumme consumerAddresses is variable in jsp which has that arry value
 for(int x=0;x<consumerAddresses.length;x++) {%>
  
         $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" id="label<%=x%>" value='<%=consumerAddresses[x]%>'/>
         <input type="text" id="address<%=x%>" value='<%=consumerAddresses[x]%>'/></div>');
<%}%>
```

**Note** : Above code is not tested it might be having some syntax error .Also, you can do same using jstl .